# Can't put more than one number in the textbox. in my Simple Calculator program

Tags: c#

Need help in making a simple calculator. i can't put more than one number in my calculator's textbox. Everytime i put a second number it replaces the first one need help!

I can't exceed more than one input number in my Calculator's Textbox instead it replaces the first number with a second number input

```
namespace Calculator_Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InputOutputArea_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void One_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Input = 1;
            InputOutputArea.Text = Input.ToString();
        }

        private void Two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Input = 2;
            InputOutputArea.Text = Input.ToString();
        }

        private void Three_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Four_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Five_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Six_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Seven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Eight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Nine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Eql_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AddB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MultiplyB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DivideB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Zero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ResetB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputOutputArea.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `InputOutputArea.Text +=` instead of `InputOutputArea.Text =` to add text instead of replacing it.

Comment: Yes, that's because you are overwriting the value of textbox on each click - Instead, you can write "InputOutputArea.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}", InputOutputArea.Text, Input.ToString());"

Answer (score 1):

You should use 
`InputOutputArea.Text += Input.ToString();` 
(note the '+') in order to append to a text box.

Comment: Hope that this line is an over burden `int Input = 2;`, Declared as `int` no future use at all, converted as string again, Then why not simply `InputOutputArea.Text += "2";`

Comment: @un-lucky Yes, that would be an improvement to the code. An even more efficient way of coding this, would be to use a shared event handler for all the numeric buttons and simply append the label of the sender Button (which in a calculator presumably would be the number in question) to the InputOutputArea Text property.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void Two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Input = 2;
        InputOutputArea.Text += Input.ToString();
    }
```

You must use += to add other text to next of first text

Comment: Hope that this line is an over burden `int Input = 2;`, Declared as `int` no future use at all, converted as string again, Then why not simply `InputOutputArea.Text += "2";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
InputOutputArea.Text = Input.ToString();
```

This replaces the content of the textbox instead of adding to it.

```
InputOutputArea.Text += Input.ToString();
```

the above code should do as you ask.

Good to remember is that concatenating strings with `+` is rather inefficient, so don't do this in performance critical code unless absolutely necessary. In those cases a String-builder is almost always better.

Answer (score 1):

Every answers talking about the Concatenation of the previous text with the current, But I would like to suggest something more than that;

You need not to create separate event handlers for all your buttons that are doing same tasks, Hope that the Text of each button will be the number that you need to display in the textBox(say `btnOne` will holds `1` and `btnTwo`holds `2` and so on). By make use of this Text we  can reuse the handlers like the following, Let `btnNumber_Click` be the handler and which is defined like the following:

```
private void btnNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button currentButton = sender as Button;
    InputOutputArea.Text += currentButton.Text;
}
```